# idxmax() returns index instead of timestaped

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, max

a python beginner here,

I am trying to get the highest price of a particular stock per month, and what date the maximum value occurred.

Getting the maximum value per month is okay using `max()`

but when I'm trying get the corresponding dates of the max price using `idxmax()`, my code returns the corresponding index instead of date. My code looks like this:

```
Max_Date = Daily_High.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="M")).High.idxmax()
```

**Output**

```
Date    High    
0   2020-04-30  9929
1   2020-05-31  9946
2   2020-06-30  9966
3   2020-07-31  9993
4   2020-08-31  10014
5   2020-09-30  10016
6   2020-10-31  10044
7   2020-11-30  10063
8   2020-12-31  10097
9   2021-01-31  10114
10  2021-02-28  10125
11  2021-03-31  10139
12  2021-04-30  10180
13  2021-05-31  10182
```

**Output Should be like this**

```
Date    High    Max Date
0   2020-04-30  2020-04-30
1   2020-05-31  2020-05-26
2   2020-06-30  2020-06-23
3   2020-07-31  2020-07-31
4   2020-08-31  2020-08-31
5   2020-09-30  2020-09-02
6   2020-10-31  2020-10-13
7   2020-11-30  2020-11-09
8   2020-12-31  2020-12-29
9   2021-01-31  2021-01-25
10  2021-02-28  2021-02-09
11  2021-03-31  2021-03-02
12  2021-04-30  2021-04-29
13  2021-05-31  2021-05-03
```

Hope you can help me to get the correct date. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `DatetimeIndex` and remove `key="Date"` from `pd.Grouper`:

```
Max_Date = Daily_High.set_index('Date').groupby(pd.Grouper( freq="M")).High.idxmax()
```